# Programmatically add Keyword and URL to Chrome "Other Search Engines"

Tags: google-chrome

I recently discovered the ability to add a "shortcut" accessible via Chromes address bar.

https://superuser.com/questions/468547/how-can-i-create-a-url-shortcut-in-chrome

For my job we manage a large number of customers websites, that we assign a specific number to. My goal is to tie the customer number to their specific URL via the steps outlined in the above URL.

Does anyone know how to programmatically add these values? I can run them in manually, but If I could take advantage of an API or other tech it could prove useful.

Answer (score 5):

Since the SQLite database for Chrome settings is now encrypted, it's harder to edit this directly.

I've managed to import search keywords into Chrome by generating an HTML bookmark file, which looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Bookmarks</H1>
<DL>
<p>
    
    <DT><A HREF="chrome://history/search#q=%s" SHORTCUTURL="hi">history</A></DT>
    <DT><A HREF="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&amp;search=%s" SHORTCUTURL="w">Wikipedia</A></DT>
    <DT><A HREF="http://www.wordreference.com/definition/%s" SHORTCUTURL="en">Wordref Eng</A></DT>
    <DT><A HREF="https://www.google.com/maps/place/%s" SHORTCUTURL="map">Google maps</A></DT>
    <DT><A HREF="https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%s" SHORTCUTURL="g">Google</A></DT>

</p>
</DL>
```

You can import this via (Chrome menu) => Bookmarks => Import bookmarks and settings => (select "Bookmarks HTML file") => Choose file

I'm not sure if it's possible to automate the actual import process, but it's easy enough to generate the HTML programmatically.

When you export bookmarks from Chrome, these will not be included. You can edit them within Chrome though by going to Settings => Search Engines (chrome://settings/searchEngines). When updating search engines, the keyword / shortcuturl field seems to be used as the key.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome Search Engines are stored in the **Web Data** file (which is an SQLite database) in the following location depending on the operating system.

- Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`
- Windows: `C:\<User>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` in Windows XP and `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` in Windows Vista and onwards
- Linux: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/`

To get all the search engine enter the command: `select * from keywords`.

To add a search engine, you need to add an entry to the `keywords` table. (Make sure you quit chrome before making any changes to the database)

Comment: its encrypted. Do you know what the password would be?